# Como deixa a div sempre com o tamanho máximo da página?

Tags: html, css

Como é possível fazer com que a `<div>` conteúdo tenha como tamanho minimo o tamanho da pagina em qualquer resolução ou monitor sem criar barra de rolagem?

Sendo que barra de rolagem só deve existir quando o conteúdo da `<div>` conteúdo estiver preenchido o suficiente para isso.

Código atual:

```css
    html,
    body,
    .maximoHeight {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #cabecalho {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    #conteudo {
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    #rodape {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server" class="maximoHeight">
    <div class="container maximoHeight">

      <div id="cabecalho" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="conteudo" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphConteudo" runat="server">
          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="rodape" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **width: 100%** resolve ? ( para largura ) e **height: 100%** para altura

Comment: @Rafael Kendrik o 100vh fez a div ficar com o 100% mas como eu tenho cabecalho e rodape cada um com 100px ele cria a barra de rolagem e esconde meu rodapé.

Comment: @SneepS NinjA, não resolve por que como tenho cabeçalho e rodapé com 100px cada e ele esconde o rodapé.

Comment: Por que a pergunta esta sendo negativada, a algo errado nela?

Comment: Se vc está utilizando bootstrap, leia sobre as definições de "containers" no boostrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container , `container-fluid` e `container`

Comment: lembrando que você pode personalizar também o CSS, onde você pode especificar tamanhos `max-width` e `min-height` para qualquer elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma utilizando o *calc*, com ele você evita utilizar *position absolute* ou *javascript* (ou *Jquery*) forçando muitas vezes o *reflow* e sobreposição de elementos com *z-index*, sem falar que evita diversos bugs e é suportado em quase todos os navegadores, com exceção de alguns *browsers* para mobile, o quais não são preocupantes, pois normalmente há rolagem no eixo vertical da pagina no mobile ou seja a barra de rolagem que você disse.

Utilize o seguinte código:

```css
/*Resets*/ 
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


html,
 body,
 .maximoHeight {
   height: 100%;
 }
 #cabecalho {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: red;
 }
 #conteudo {
   min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
   background-color: yellow;
 }
 #rodape {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: green;
 }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server" class="maximoHeight">
    <div class="container maximoHeight">

      <div id="cabecalho" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="conteudo" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphConteudo" runat="server">
          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="rodape" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

*Clique no botão "página toda" para ver o resultado por completo.*

Explicação: apenas troquei o valor da *min-height* pelo *calc*, subtraindo 100vh (ou a altura total da *viewport*) pela altura dos demais itens que compõem o documento (no caso 200px). Após adicionei um *resets* básico para remover `margin` e `padding` e adicionar um `box-sizing: border-box` para todos os elementos, evitando assim a barra de rolagem:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

OBS.: recomendo a utilização de *vendor prefixes* para o *calc*, atualmente apenas é necessário utilizar *-webkit* e a propriedade propriamente dita.

Comment: Cara sua solução funcionou perfeitamente aqui no projeto da empresa, muito obrigado era exatamente o que eu precisava, eu não conhecia essa função do calc nem mesmo esse 100vh.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz, obrigado pelo feedback, qualquer dúvida a respeito, pode perguntar!!

Answer (score 1):

Boas, Utilize jQuery para verificar o tamanho da janela do cliente que está renderizando a sua pagina.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  setHeight100();    
 });

 $(window).resize(function(){
  setHeight100(); 
 });

 function setHeight100(){
  alturaTotal = $(window).height();

  alturaProvavelNecessaria = alturaTotal - ( $('#cabecalho').height() + $('#rodape').height());

  $('#conteudo').css('overflow','auto').height(alturaProvavelNecessaria);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Israel sua solução também funcionou.